# Regular expression in an Apache Velocity template to check if a string contains a URL

Tags: java, regex, velocity

I'm trying to write a regular expression in an Apache Velocity template to check if a string contains a URL.

My code is below.  The variable $quoteValue is currently set to contain the string "This is a pullquote test: http://www.google.com"

```
##Set the regular expression to be used to find a URL
            #set($urlRegex = '(.*)(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?(.*)')
            Is there a match? $quoteValue.matches($urlRegex)
```

However, the $quoteValue.matches($urlRegex) method always returns false, when I would expect it to return true in this case.  How can I get it to recognise that the string contains a URL? I'm assuming this is something to do with escaping special characters.

Comment: Most probably the backslashes must be doubled. The [regex seems to work](https://regex101.com/r/bS6sU3/1).

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried doubling the backslashes, but it's still returning false.

Comment: I see, you are using single quotes around the pattern, really, doubling the backslashes is not necessary. If there are no newline symbols, `.*` should match. If not, you need to add `(?s)` at the pattern start. Also, try with a very simple regex like `(?s).*http.*` - if it fails, the problem is not with a regex at all, but how you are using it.

Comment: Adding (?s) to the start of the regular expression has made it work.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue using the following code for the regular expression:

```
#set($urlRegex = '(?s).*(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?.*')
```

It was the (?s) at the start which made it work!

Answer (score 2):

`.matches()` is implicitly anchored with `^$`

In other words, it only returns true when the entire thing matches.

Replace it with `.find()`.